# hosting PHP application within moodle LMS

Tags: php, moodle

Good day, I would like to know if there is a way to run a php application within the moodle LMS.

Prior to implementation in php, the information was in the form of static html documents, which were simply uploaded into folder and accessing the files gave the appearance of a site hosted within moodle.

Can such a functionality be replicated using PHP files that require service processing for desired features.

If not what are the best options for giving users a similar experience.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use plugins(Blocks or Module) to develop applications within Moodle. The pre-condition is that you need to follow Moodle programming guidelines to create a plugin.

More details here:

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Modules

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Blocks

However, you need to decide whether you need a Block or an Activity Module and it can be determined only after seeing the requirements.